# Using GridFS to store large JSON structure

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I am new to MongoDB and I am struggling to figure out if MongoDB GridFS is a right choice for my use-case. I have a large JSON which I want to store in the DB. The JSON has following format

```
{
    "task":"12345",
    "items":[ 
                item1: [subitem11:[f1,f2,..fn],subitem12:[f1,f2,..fm],....,subitem1n:[f1,f2,..fk]],
                item2: [subitem21:[f1,f2,..fn],subitem22:[f1,f2,..fm],....,subitem1m:[f1,f2,..fk]].
                .
                .
                itemn:[subitemn1:[f1,f2,..fn],subitemn2:[f1,f2,..fm],....,subitemnk:[f1,f2,..fk]]
            ],
}
```

The item and subitem are string arrays and can be very large.

The JSON size can be as large as 250MB(worst case) and there can be many documents in the DB. My read/write pattern is as follows.

**Write:** Given task and/or item and/or subitem I want to be able to update item or subitem array

**Read:**  Given either task and/or  items and/or subitems I want to be able to read the subarrays

My questions are as follows:

1. Is there a way I can store such a large JSON and still be able to update/read it as quickly using MongoDB GridFS?  From what I understand MongoDB GridFS splits large files like video files into chunks and store those chunks. It is not clear to me how MongoDB will split the large JSON and how I will be able to quickly perform read and write operations.
2. Is MongoDB a right choice for this type of data. If not, what other databases can I consider? Note: I want to scale this application future and each document/item/subitem is independent of other i.e there is no relationship in the data.

I tried searching for this over internet and also referred to the MongoDB documentation but was not able to figure this out.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/

Thanks in advance for your pointers.

Answer (score 1):

GridFS allows one to store and retrieve a large file. It does not implement any operations on the file's contents.

Given the apparent structure of your data, I would suggest creating an `items` collection and inserting each item as a document into that collection.